# Hibernate SELECT on Composite Key gives unexpected char error

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key

I have a table called printer with 3 varchar2 fields making a composite id, a Printer.java class, and a PrinterID.java class (for the composite ID).

```
@Entity
public class Printer implements java.io.Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides(
        {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "rep", column = @Column(name = "REP", nullable = false, length = 30)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "quarter", column = @Column(name = "QUARTER", nullable = false, length = 2)),

            @AttributeOverride(name = "product", column = @Column(name = "PRODUCT", nullable = false, length = 20)),
        }
    )
    private PrinterId id;


@Embeddable
public class PrinterId implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String rep;
    private String quarter;
    private String product;
```

Code within of another class...

```
private Printer getPrinter(String a, String b, String c) {
    Session session = // code to get and open a session
    session.beginTransaction
    PrinterId compId = new PrinterId(a, b, c);
    Printer aPrinter = (Printer) session.load(Printer.class, compId);
    return aPrinter;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '@' [from Printer where
>   id = PrinterId@77c95c8b]

What's up with the "@77c95c8b" - Is that from the PrinterId.hashCode() method? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrinterId@77c95c8b looks to be the output of Object.toString() -- which uses the hash value, as you suspected. So first thing that will help is to @Override the toString() method of PrinterId to provide a nice output (Eclipse and most other IDEs can generate it for you). Something like:

```java
public String toString() {
    return "PrinterId:" + rep + "," + quarter + "," + product;
}
```

However, I wouldn't expect Hibernate to try to convert the id to a string when you use session.load(), because you have overridden the attributes and anyway it would parameterize the query. I suspect that you are somewhere creating an SQL query and building it directly with the id, hence implicitly using the toString method, perhaps:

```java
"SELECT ... FROM printer WHERE id = " + printerId;
```

This can be avoided by parameterizing the query.

If you really are only using session.load then please leave me a comment.

Comment: I've tried several things. First, I tried it inline, like you suspected. That failure makes total sense - it's not a String. Since then I've tried:
PrinterId compId = new PrinterId(a, b, c);
Printer aPrinter = (Printer) session.createQuery("select p from Printer p where id = :comp")
 .setString(":comp", compId)
 .setString(":b", b)
 .setString(":c", c)
 .uniqueResult();
Also:
Printer aPrinter = (Printer) session.createQuery("select p from Printer p where A = :a and B = :b and C = :c")
 .setString(":a", a)
 .setString(":b", b)
 .setString(":c", c)
 .uniqueResult();
They all give the same error.

Comment: How about session.get(Printer.class, id) ? You shouldn't need to create your own query just to get a single instance by id

Comment: I found the error. I'm a bit embarrassed to say, but you're spot on. The get() was working fine. There was a subsequent call that was inline, where the toString() method was automatically getting called. Thanks for pointing me to look for that.